# Is there a way to make a process static in linux without recompiling it?

Tags: linux, shared-libraries, static-libraries, static-linking

I have a binary file that requires several shared libraries. I want to distribute it without the additional files. Is there a way to statically link it using only the binary and the libraries?

Comment: Is a wrapper that unpacks the main executable and its libraries just-in-time an option?  One could even conceive of a virtual filesystem that prevents the files from ever being placed on disk.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No there is no way to transform a program dynamically linking some libraries to a program statically linking them.

But why do you ask? Can't you ship a shell wrapper which sets appropriately the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` before running the binary?

Comment: I was trying to avoid shipping so many files. In the end, I gave up and did just that.